# select and deselect checkboxes with parent checkbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to select/deselect child check boxes based on parent check boxes i need this in angularjs anyone please give the solution

i want like this

[image]

Comment: Please provide code that you worked on

Answer (score 1):

The ng-checked attribute in the checkbox takes in an expression. So you can give an expression with and/or conditions, as mentioned below to make it checked based on an expression.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="child_1 && child_2 && child_3 && child_4 && child_5" ng-model="parent"/> Select All<br/>
```

You dont have to write a seprate function to do the computation when every child checkbox is clicked.

In above example 
Child Check box model: child_1, child_2, child_3, child_4, child_5
Parent Check box model : parent
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pio123/624y6/1/)

Comment: I want parents have multiple checkboxes

Comment: have you see example provided link ?

Comment: yes my childs data came from api i will use ng-repeat to display th child checkboxes and parent checkboxes also